# response.readEntity() throws UnrecognizedPropertyException when jackson serializer and deserializer use different naming

Tags: jackson

I have a unit test where I want to check the response that I return in my endpoint. My problem is that when I call `Response#readEntity(MyPojo.class)` I get the `UnrecognizedPropertyException` the reason for this is probably, which I am well aware of, that in my POJO class:

```
public class Answer {
    @NotNull
    private QuestionNames questionId;

    @NotNull
    private Integer optionId;

    @JsonProperty("optionId")
    public void setOptionId(@NotNull Integer optionId) {
        this.optionId = optionId;
    }

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("value")
    public Integer getValue() {
        return this.optionId;
    }

    @NotNull
    public QuestionNames getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }

    public void setQuestionId(@NotNull QuestionNames questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }
}
```

The reason for having it like this is because I have to return answers to the clients where the `optionId` is named as `value` but when they send in new answers with values they call it `optionId`. Now I can easily solve the problem by just creating two POJOs with same fields just the value field is named differently so basically just having:

```
public class AnswerIn {
    private QuestionNames questionId;
    private Integer optionId;
}

public class AnswerOut {
    private QuestionNames questionId;
    private Integer value;
}
```

and then just use the `AnswerOut` in my `GET` endpoint and `AnswerIn` in the `POST` but this seems just cumbersome and stupid.

I have tested my solution manually and works perfectly fine considering how it is going to be used. But when I write my UnitTest it fails because it cannot ready the response entity properly getting `Unrecognized field "value" (class com.test.Answer), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "optionId", "questionId"])`

Using `jackson 2.7.8` and `jdk 1.8`

Comment: Given that you have two different types of JSON object (one with a value field and one with an optionId field) I don't think having two classes to reflect that is cumbersome. Solutions which combine the two are likely to be less clear and may validate the object less strictly (adding ignoreUnknown will allow other unknown fields too)

Comment: I think that you are right @mattfreake Think I just need a confirmation from someone else and yeah probably not cumbersome, I just thought that it was a bit weird having two classes the same just different field naming. But seems like I will go back to having two classes. Thanks.

Comment: Annotate the `Answer` class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`